# What does `template <class> friend class Foo` mean?

Tags: c++, boost, friend

I'm exploring the boost::iterator_facade and came across this bit of code:

```
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
    template <class> friend class Iterator;
```

What does the second line mean? I'm familiar with friend classes, but I don't think I've seen `template <class>` in front of anything before.

---

Here's the context:

```
template <class Value>
class node_iter
  : public boost::iterator_facade<
        node_iter<Value>
      , Value
      , boost::forward_traversal_tag
    >
{
 public:
    node_iter()
      : m_node(0) {}

    explicit node_iter(Value* p)
      : m_node(p) {}

    template <class OtherValue>
    node_iter(node_iter<OtherValue> const& other)
      : m_node(other.m_node) {}

 private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
    template <class> friend class node_iter;

    template <class OtherValue>
    bool equal(node_iter<OtherValue> const& other) const
    {
        return this->m_node == other.m_node;
    }

    void increment()
    { m_node = m_node->next(); }

    Value& dereference() const
    { return *m_node; }

    Value* m_node;
};
typedef impl::node_iterator<node_base> node_iterator;
typedef impl::node_iterator<node_base const> node_const_iterator;
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Comment: `class node_iter` is a friend to itself here. It looks like this line maybe redundant as a class is a friend to itself by default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just means `Iterator` is a template class with one template parameter. The friendship is granted to all instantiations of `Iterator`.

`Iterator<int>` is a friend of the class.

`Iterator<bool>` is a friend of the class.

...

`Iterator<MyClass>` is a friend of the class.

You get the idea.

**Example Usage**

Say you have a class template `Foo`.

```
template <typename T> class Foo
{
   public:
      Foo() : data(0) {}
   prvavte:
      T data;
};
```

When you instantiate the class template using:

```
Foo<int> a;
Foo<float> b;
```

you are creating two classes at compile time. `Foo<int>` does not have access to the private section of `Foo<float>` and vice versa. That is an inconvenience some times.

You can't do:

```
b = a;  // If you wanted to pull the data from a and put it in b.
```

Even if you added an assignment operator to the class,

```
template <typename T> class Foo
{
   public:
      Foo() : data(0) {}
      template <typename T2> Foo& operator=(Foo<T2> const& rhs)
      {
         this->data = rhs.data;
         return *this;
      }

   private:
      T data;
};
```

It won't work because `Foo<T>` doesn't have access to the private sections of `Foo<T2>`. To get around that you can use a friend declaration.

```
template <typename T> class Foo
{
   public:
      template <class> friend class Foo;
      Foo() : data(0) {}
      template <typename T2> Foo& operator=(Foo<T2> const& rhs)
      {
         this->data = rhs.data;
         return *this;
      }

   private:
      T data;
};
```

Now, you can use:

```
Foo<int> a;
Foo<float> b;
b = a;
```

Comment: Ah, I think the part I was missing is basically that `template <class>` contains an unnamed template parameter. I guess that just rarely comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit Instantiation: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1C75fSEw/

It allows you to instantiate the template without actually using it.